# Is there a name for argument-scaled differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When I look up "scaling differential equations" I don't get related results, when I look up "dilated differential equations" I don't get related results.

Is there a formal name for a differential equation of the form

$y'(t)=y(at)$?

Or is the solution so trivial that it doesn't need a name?

Comment: Delay differential equations? Far from trivial, I assure you.

Comment: DDE are of the form $y'(t)=ay(t)+by(t-c)+dy(t-e)...$, I have never seen a DDE with $y(at)$.

Comment: The definition just says that the functions and their derivatives aren't evaluated at the same points in time, which is true for your equation.

Comment: But they would be evaluated at same point at least one point in time without the delay, since $at=t$ has the solution $t=0$. With $t=t-a$ there is no solution at all besides $a=0$ which then makes it no longer a DDE.

Comment: I don't think that's an issue in the definition. After all, $y''(t)+y'(t)-y(t-c)=0$ is a DDE, and the derivative and second derivative are evaluated at the same point.

Comment: Well if you can find a DDE paper that has a $y(at)$ in it, feel free to share it. Every paper I've seen only has an additive/subtractive delay.

Comment: Definition at wolfram (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDelayDifferentialEquations.html) says, "... The delays may be constants, functions $\tau(t)$ and $\sigma(t)$ of $t$ (time-dependent delays), ..."

Comment: Pantograph equation at the wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation): $\dot{x}(t)=ax(t)+b x(\lambda t),$ which is actually your equation with $a=0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation is the pantograph equation $\dot{x}(t)=a x(t)+bx(\lambda t)$ with $a=0.$ It is a type of delay differential equation. [See the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation). [Here is a paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042716300723) on the pantograph equation that uses Bernstein polynomials.